# Multidimensional string array thrown out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am quite new to Java. I am trying to add a name onto the end of this multidimensional array.

```
    String[][] cartoons = new String [][] {
    { "Flintstones", "Fred", "Wilma", "Pebbles", "Dino" },
    { "Rubbles", "Barney", "Betty", "Bam Bam" },
    { "Jetsons", "George", "Jane", "Elroy", "Judy", "Rosie", "Astro" },
    { "Scooby Doo Gang", "Scooby Doo", "Shaggy", "Velma", "Fred", "Daphne" } };


  cartoons[0][5] = "VELMA";

  System.out.println(cartoons[0][5]);
```

As you can see it is thrown out of bounds.

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:46)
Java Result: 1
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: There are only 5 values in `cartoons[0]`, and Java arrays are not resizable.

Comment: What would you recommend to fix this, or use instead? I like the simplicity of the calling style.

Answer (score 2):

You Have 5 elements in `cartoons[0]` that means the access index from `cartoons[0][0]` to `cartoons[0][4]`

and here

> cartoons[0][5] = "VELMA";

you want to access 6th index which is actually out of bounds

that's why you are getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>       at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:46)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add this element to the list.

Comment: you are declaring and defining array at the same time and in java array is not resizable, so you can't add more elements to the same array. Instead to do this you can use Vector or ArrayList, both are resizable.

Answer (score 0):

In java, array is not resizable, But you can use list:

```
    List<List<String>> parentList = new ArrayList<>();
    // initialize the parent list
    for (String[] strs : cartoons) {
        ArrayList<String> subList = new ArrayList<>();
        subList.addAll(Arrays.asList(strs)); // initialize the sub list
        parentList.add(subList);
    }

    parentList.get(0).add("VELMA"); // add the element

    System.out.println(parentList.get(0).get(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add to an array in Java (because they aren't dynamically sized), but you could use [`Arrays.copyOf(T[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) which (per the Javadoc) *Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if necessary) so the copy has the specified length.* Since you want to add one element, that might look something like

```
cartoons[0] = Arrays.copyOf(cartoons[0], cartoons[0].length + 1);
cartoons[0][5] = "VELMA";
```